# вывести html страницу из servleta по GET/POST запросу в jetty

Tags: java, post, get, servlet, jetty

Подскажите как вывести страницу из servleta по `GET/POST` запросу в `jetty`.
Мои классы.

```
public class startServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AllRequestsServlet allRequestsServlet = new AllRequestsServlet();
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/aser", ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(allRequestsServlet), "/*");

        server.setHandler(context);
        server.start();
        System.out.println("Server started");
        server.join();
    }
}
```

servlet

```
public class AllRequestsServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                      HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
    }
}
```

что бы вывести текст я в методе `GET/POST` прописываю

```
response.getWriter().print("...");
```

что и где мне надо указать что бы выводилась html страница, например index.html которая расположена в **src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/index.html**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В папке WEB-INF находятся те статичные файлы, которые доступны без сервлетов.
А шаблоны, на основе которых генерируется ответ сервлетов, обычно хранятся в /src/main/resources/...
Их считать в поток можно так:
`getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( "/templates/..." )`
Потом этот поток можно передать в ваш шаблонизатор, например, velocity, а результат работы шаблонизатора вывести в `response.getWriter()`.